# Dual boot multi-drive grub errors

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive, bootloader

I have 2 drives. One is NVME and one is a hard drive. Windows in on the NVME. I wanted to try Ubuntu so installed it on the HD (a couple of months ago). I got grub working just fine. The issue was the HD was miserably slow. So now I want to re-install Ubuntu onto a partition of my NVME.

But here's the issue. Grub wont let me boot windows without the HD with Ubuntu. I get the error "Error: no such device". I installed Grub2Win on my Windows installation, but it doesn't see Ubuntu, and I try unplugging the HD, and I get the same Grub error.

My goal is to have Windows and Ubuntu on my NVME, and have a bootloader on one (doesn't matter which).
I don't know how to get rid of the Ubuntu on the HD, without making my Windows installation useless. (the Ubuntu HD has no data on it and can be formatted if needed, and likely will when I'm done).

Grub has some options to hide itself, but that would just bypass bootloader, and boot to whichever os you  you set.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS based system and then is Windows UEFI or BIOS boot mode? This cannot fix Windows in most cased, but will show details. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You can just reinstall ubuntu (on nvme) and set your grub location to the ssd. Next, you can set your bios boot device to your nvme ssd. This will then boot to the new grub with the new ubuntu. O jea, and also don't install any os on a hard drive except when you don't have ssd. Its always slow :)